# Is it possible to resize image file on Java DD4T?

Tags: dd4t, java, binary

I'm making WEB site by Java DD4T.

On .NET version, it's very easy to resize image.
But on Java version, I can't find how to do that, even though I searched source codes.

Is there any out-of-box functionality to resize image on Java DD4T?

Or is it required that creating such functionality by myself?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such a function in Java, an aproach could be to run it through media manager that supports image resizing.

Side question; which version of DD4T java are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 1.31. I'll create image resizing function by myself.

Comment: Would recommend you to use this one; https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/tree/release